# Post call in Spring Boot and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I'm developing a simple Spring Boot / React application for managing Products.

When the user goes to a Create Product form in React, which is the best practique:

A) Call the API and GET an empty Product object, populate it and POST it back with filled data

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public ModelMap addProduct(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Product product) {
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.addAttribute("product", new Product());

    return model;
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public String saveNewProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product) {
    ...
    productService.getRepository().save(product);

    return "redirect:/products/list";
}
```

B) Just create the form in React and do the POST call

Thanks

Comment: b - i have to have 14 characters but b.

Comment: thanks @mikeb, makes sense I'll go for the B option then.